# What is the `~/log/dr-monero/net` directory?

Tags: monerod, logs

When I stop the `monerod` daemon, I can remove the `~/log` directory. As soon as I restart the daemon process, it gets recreated. I don't what this cluttering up my home directory, so:

- What is it?
- Why is it there?
- How do I get rid of it (i.e. move to a hidden directory)?

**Update:** I think this was previously stored under `~/.bitmonero`, but as of recently, I suppose with the 0.10.1.0 release, the location seems to have moved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dr. Monero was a logging scheme that Rafal "rfree" Freeman created. It was meant to provide statistics and data useful for improving the wire protocol. Unfortunately it was never really completed, and just ended up creating a third logging sub-system.

We're in the process of removing all three logging sub-systems and replacing them with a single known-good library (instead of rolling our own), so this will eventually go away. In the meantime you can either ignore it, or remove it, but it'll be re-created.